# meatballs refrozen, safe to eat

Tags: food-safety

freezer broke and i did not find out until all the items, meatballs in a bag, vegetables had defrosted, however, there was still ice and ice water from the ice accumulated during the months and the temperature outside and in garage was in the teens for 2 weeks. i am saying the temp in the broken freezer was just above the freezing temp, i think.  Would the vegetable and meatballs, chicken, and pork chops be safe to eat, i did refreeze them when i discovered the problem.

Comment: Do you know what temperature the freezer was at when you found it?  If it was still below 40°F, you could treat it as if it were thawed in the fridge and just cook & use it immediately.  If you think it might've failed in warmer weather and came down because of a recent cold spell, then it's more clearly a 'trash all of the meat and use the vegetables to make stock' type situation.

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/24123/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/42489/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/47146/67

Comment: "In the teens" doesn't sound like "above freezing temp". First of all, we don't know whether your numbers are supposed to be in °C or °F. "Teens" in C is way above freezing temperature, and in F it's actually below freezing temperature. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The vegetables might be fine, since vegetables can be stored in the fridge for up to a few weeks, depending on the kind. The meat should be thrown out. If you don't know at what temperature it has been kept, and for how long, there is no way to tell if it is still safe, and food poisoning is unpleasant. I would throw everything out, but I strongly recommend at least all the meat.